# Symfony2 DOMCrawler selectLink returns null uri

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I have a problem with writing functional tests and DOMCrawler. My issue is to crawl through mail content with link. From docs i saw that the crawler can be created with html content as parameter. So this is my chunk of code:

```
$mailCrawler = new Crawler($message->getBody());
$linkCrawler = $mailCrawler->selectLink('Link name');
$client->click($linkCrawler->link());
```

On third line I have an exception because $linkCrawler has empty $uri field.
Exception message:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Current URI must be an absolute URL ("").
```

Can anyone tell me why crawler cant get that link?

I can only tell that the $message var  getBody method returns correct content.

Regards

Comment: First guess is that 'Link Name is not on your page.  `var_dump(mailCrawler->selectLink('Link name'));` and verify it is not empty.

Comment: Well looks like it is. I have another email functional tests and same problem now. Link exists but somehow uri is empty when do this var_dump

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify root crawler url. Example:

```
$crawler = new Crawler('', 'http://www.example.com');
$crawler->addHtmlContent("
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <a href=\"/rel-link\">rel-link-text</a>
            <a href=\"http://another.com/abs-link\">abs-link-text</a>
        </body>
    </html>
", 'UTF-8');

$cLink1 = $crawler->selectLink('rel-link-text')->eq(0);
$l1 = $cLink1->link();
echo $l1->getUri(); // http://www.example.com/rel-link

$cLink2 = $crawler->selectLink('abs-link-text')->eq(0);
$l2 = $cLink2->link();
echo $l2->getUri(); // http://another.com/abs-link
```